# Proving concentration from CDF

Tags: probability, concentration-of-measure

I having some trouble proving Lemma 5 of http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dmcallester/margins.ps
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I want to prove the following:

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable such that $Pr(X \leq x) \leq e^{-m f(x)}$, where $f(x)$ is non-negative. Then 
$$Pr(e^{(m-1)f(X)} \geq \nu) \leq min(1, \nu^{-m/(m-1)}).$$

The only thing I can think would be applicable here is the Markov's inequality but the result does not follow from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the inequality follows from pure algebra but not without additional assumptions on the function $f$. For instance, it seems like $f(x)$ has to be a decreasing function of $x$ and invertible.
\begin{align*}
Pr(e^{(m-1) f(X)} \geq \nu) &= Pr(e^{-(m-1) f(X)} \leq \nu^{-1}) \\
&= Pr(e^{-f(X)} \leq \nu^{-1/(m-1)}) \\
&= Pr(-f(X) \leq \ln \nu^{-1/(m-1)}) \\
&= Pr(f(X) \geq \ln \nu^{1/(m-1)}) \\
&= Pr(X \leq f^{-1}(\ln \nu^{1/(m-1)}))  && (\text{Here we use that f is decreasing}) \\
&\leq \exp\{-m \ln \nu^{1/(m-1)}\} = \nu^{-m/(m-1)}
\end{align*}